# If objects (x,y) are near other objects (x,y)

Tags: java, math, if-statement, coordinates

I have two separate objects in Java, `Object1` and `Object2`, both are the same size and square. For each object I can get the *x* and *y* coordinates. What I need to do is check if `Object1` is within a certain distance of `Object2`. That distance is within 32 points on both the *X* and *Y* axis.

once the condition has been met then I can run my code. e.g.

```
    if ( check condition ) {
    //my code here
    }
```

Comment: do you have the object width?

Comment: which is de width of the objects? and also: are the (x,y) attributes the center of each object, or a corner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if(Math.abs(Object1.x - Object2.x) <= 32 && Math.abs(Object1.y - Object2.y) <= 32)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Also, check into Euclidean Distance and the Pythagorean Formula.

Comment: @AlexW Well, he is using the `Maximum-Distance` or `Chebyshev-Distance`, which is the `Minkowski-Distance` for p=infinity. Depending on his application, this is appropriate. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance

Comment: This only works if both the objects have a surface equals to zero... which is de width of the objects? and also: are the (x,y) attributes the center of each object, or a corner?

Comment: @Barranka It works if you only measure the the distance between their centers or any fixed corner. Since he did not specify his question in more detail, this is all I can give him.

Answer (score 3):

If these are rectangles and not points, you need to compensate for their width and height.  Since they're squares, just use their width if you have it

```
if(Math.abs(Object1.X - Object2.X) <= 32 + Object1.Width && Math.abs(Object1.Y - Object2.Y) <= 32 + Object1.Width)
{
    // my code here
}
```